# Python 3.4 installation error 1 (OSError [errno 22] Invalid argument)

Tags: python, linux, makefile, centos, python-3.4

I'm trying to install (altinstall) various versions of Python from source code. I tried to install Python 3.5.2, but have a this error every time. Now i'm trying to install Python 3.4.4 and nothing changes, error below:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '/tmp/tmpxrdqva80'
make: *** [altinstall] Error 1
```

Full traceback for this error:

```
Collecting setuptools
Collecting pip
Installing collected packages: setuptools, pip
Successfully installed pip-7.1.2 setuptools-18.2
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/tmpxrdqva80/pip-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/basecommand.py", line 211, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/tmp/tmpxrdqva80/pip-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/commands/install.py", line 344, in run
    requirement_set.cleanup_files()
  File "/tmp/tmpxrdqva80/pip-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/utils/build.py", line 38, in __exit__
    self.cleanup()
  File "/tmp/tmpxrdqva80/pip-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/utils/build.py", line 42, in cleanup
    rmtree(self.name)
  File "/tmp/tmpxrdqva80/pip-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/retrying.py", line 49, in wrapped_f
    return Retrying(*dargs, **dkw).call(f, *args, **kw)
  File "/tmp/tmpxrdqva80/pip-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/retrying.py", line 212, in call
    raise attempt.get()
  File "/tmp/tmpxrdqva80/pip-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/retrying.py", line 247, in get
    six.reraise(self.value[0], self.value[1], self.value[2])
  File "/tmp/tmpxrdqva80/pip-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/six.py", line 659, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/tmp/tmpxrdqva80/pip-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/retrying.py", line 200, in call
    attempt = Attempt(fn(*args, **kwargs), attempt_number, False)
  File "/tmp/tmpxrdqva80/pip-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 90, in rmtree
    onerror=rmtree_errorhandler)
  File "/home/aligar/Python-3.4.4/Lib/shutil.py", line 468, in rmtree
    _rmtree_safe_fd(fd, path, onerror)
  File "/home/aligar/Python-3.4.4/Lib/shutil.py", line 390, in _rmtree_safe_fd
    onerror(os.listdir, path, sys.exc_info())
  File "/home/aligar/Python-3.4.4/Lib/shutil.py", line 387, in _rmtree_safe_fd
    names = os.listdir(topfd)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '/tmp/pip-build-ays0yr6q'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aligar/Python-3.4.4/Lib/runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/home/aligar/Python-3.4.4/Lib/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/aligar/Python-3.4.4/Lib/ensurepip/__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
    ensurepip._main()
  File "/home/aligar/Python-3.4.4/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 209, in _main
    default_pip=args.default_pip,
  File "/home/aligar/Python-3.4.4/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 116, in bootstrap
    _run_pip(args + [p[0] for p in _PROJECTS], additional_paths)
  File "/home/aligar/Python-3.4.4/Lib/tempfile.py", line 709, in __exit__
    self.cleanup()
  File "/home/aligar/Python-3.4.4/Lib/tempfile.py", line 713, in cleanup
    _shutil.rmtree(self.name)
  File "/home/aligar/Python-3.4.4/Lib/shutil.py", line 468, in rmtree
    _rmtree_safe_fd(fd, path, onerror)
  File "/home/aligar/Python-3.4.4/Lib/shutil.py", line 390, in _rmtree_safe_fd
    onerror(os.listdir, path, sys.exc_info())
  File "/home/aligar/Python-3.4.4/Lib/shutil.py", line 387, in _rmtree_safe_fd
    names = os.listdir(topfd)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '/tmp/tmpxrdqva80'
make: *** [altinstall] Error 1
```

After this error looks like Python installed, console coding is working, but, when i trying to install something with pip3.4 (virtualenv), or upgrade pip i have an error below:

```
[root@aligar Python-3.4.4]# pip3.4 install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-8.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 7.1.2
    Uninstalling pip-7.1.2:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-7.1.2
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 311, in run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 657, in install
    set(req_to_install.extras) - set(dist.extras)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 729, in commit_uninstall
    bin_dir = bin_py
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 152, in commit
    )
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/_vendor/retrying.py", line 49, in wrapped_f
    return Retrying(*dargs, **dkw).call(f, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/_vendor/retrying.py", line 212, in call
    raise attempt.get()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/_vendor/retrying.py", line 247, in get
    six.reraise(self.value[0], self.value[1], self.value[2])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/_vendor/six.py", line 659, in reraise
    _assertCountEqual = "assertItemsEqual"
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/_vendor/retrying.py", line 200, in call
    attempt = Attempt(fn(*args, **kwargs), attempt_number, False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 90, in rmtree
    try:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/shutil.py", line 468, in rmtree
    _rmtree_safe_fd(fd, path, onerror)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/shutil.py", line 390, in _rmtree_safe_fd
    onerror(os.listdir, path, sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/shutil.py", line 387, in _rmtree_safe_fd
    names = os.listdir(topfd)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '/tmp/pip-oppnkwcp-uninstall'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 211, in main
    )
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 344, in run
    except PreviousBuildDirError:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/utils/build.py", line 38, in __exit__
    self.cleanup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/utils/build.py", line 42, in cleanup
    rmtree(self.name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/_vendor/retrying.py", line 49, in wrapped_f
    return Retrying(*dargs, **dkw).call(f, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/_vendor/retrying.py", line 212, in call
    raise attempt.get()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/_vendor/retrying.py", line 247, in get
    six.reraise(self.value[0], self.value[1], self.value[2])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/_vendor/six.py", line 659, in reraise
    _assertCountEqual = "assertItemsEqual"
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/_vendor/retrying.py", line 200, in call
    attempt = Attempt(fn(*args, **kwargs), attempt_number, False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 90, in rmtree
    try:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/shutil.py", line 468, in rmtree
    _rmtree_safe_fd(fd, path, onerror)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/shutil.py", line 390, in _rmtree_safe_fd
    onerror(os.listdir, path, sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/shutil.py", line 387, in _rmtree_safe_fd
    names = os.listdir(topfd)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '/tmp/pip-build-2k2643lv'
```

There are no errors and warnings, when a makefile creating.
I using virtual server CentOS Linux 6.8 at physical OpenVZ core 2.6.18, there is no possibilities to update OpenVZ core in next few months.
But after all i think, that it might be problem in OpenVZ core, am i right?
I cleared previous installations of Python by deleting its files at /usr/local/, i checked rights for /tmp/ - 1777, i have access to read, write, delete and create files there. I tried to install from root, but nothing helps. 
May be i forgot about some dependencies? I did

```
yum install zlib-devel bzip2-devel sqlite sqlite-devel openssl-devel
```

and may be something more, but i didn't remember it.

Comment: were you able to solve this? I'm experiencing the same issue when installing python 3.6.4.